# Git commit, git push to GitHub, nothing more to commit, but GitHub is not updated

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have committed all changes and pushed to GitHub right after that, but the source viewer on GitHub is only showing the source from three hours ago.

> $ git status
> # On branch master
> nothing to commit, working directory clean

## Update

> git push origin

This updated the the GitHub repository, for some reason. So that fixed my problem.

I don't really see why this would help, since I assumed that it pushed to origin by default when you gave the command

> git push

Comment: Try doing `git fetch origin` and `git show FETCH_HEAD`. Does that show the last commit you pushed, or the last commit that Github's WebUI is showing?

Comment: @xbonez git fetch origin gives no output, git show FETCH_HEAD gives the diff of the last commit. Everytime I push I get user and password prompt, and when it succeed it says that it pushed to the repo, but yet it doesn't have an origin?

Comment: by "diff of the last commit", do you mean the last commit you made, or the last commit Github shows?

Comment: @xbonez I mean the last commit I made locally.

Comment: Did your push went successfully? What's the output of `git cherry`?

Comment: Maybe do `git remote -v` to confirm that `origin` is really what you think it is...

Comment: @talles output of git cherry is nothing.

Comment: @janos git remove -v says that origin fetch and push is the same URL that I am viewing in my browser, just with a .git at the end: "https://github.com/<myusername>/<myprojectname>.git"

Comment: And on GitHub you're looking at the right branch, right?

Comment: @janos yes, there is only one branch (master).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use

```
git push origin master --force
```

to force `origin` to be an exact copy of your local machine.

**USE WITH CAUTION!**